# Xcode doesn't compile C applications even though they compile perfectly via Terminal

Tags: compiler-errors, xcode5

I am a total beginner in this. I am following an online course at harvard to learn C. At first, I used to write my `.c` files using the editor of Xcode, then I will compile via terminal using this

```
clang -o FILENAME FILENAME.c -lcs50
```

If no errors are detected, I could then run with ./FILENAME.

However, I would like to start writing within an Xcode project and compile within Xcode, just because I want to learn Xcode on the way, and I feel it's a more elegant way to manage my projects. After some trial and error I managed to link the custom library and the header file, so Xcode stopped complaining about that. The problem now, is that even though I am running exactly the same code that worked via terminal Xcode has managed to find errors in it. How is that possible?

Error message:

```
"error: failed to launch '/Users/houmamkafa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/C_programming-bgvojvuvkpddkahbqqocgozwgbib/Build/Products/Debug/C_programming' -- **SBTarget is invalid**"
```

My question is twofold:

1. What is SBTarget? And why I am I getting this error? I will assume that this is related to Xcode and that's why I don't see it when I compile/run via terminal, but what is it and how to solve it?
2. Please forgive my ignorance, but can I compile and run the .c file via Xcode like I do via terminal, and if so how can I run commands like `clang -o FILENAME FILENAME.c -lcs50` in Xcode? Would I be able to test the program in Xcode? As in, when I ask for user input etc.?

Here's an example of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cube(int input);

int main(void)
{
  int x = 2;
  printf("x is %d\n", x);
  x = cube(x);
  printf("x is %d\n", x);
  fflush(stdout);
  return(0);
}

int cube(int input)
{
  int output = input * input * input;
  return (output);
}
```